# Random class-item from list every click? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am very new to Windows Forms and doing my first assignment today.
I have imported a text-file of strings and then created a List of those strings.
Then I have a method that chooses a random object-T from the list and prints it in a label when I click a specific button.
This works fine so far but my problem is that I want to generate a new object-T with every click.
Is there anyway to reset the created object after its been printed in the label? 
Appreciate any help! :)

```
namespace Tipsmaskinen2
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       FileLoader fileLoader = new FileLoader();
       Book bookRecommendation = FileLoader.RandomBook();

       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void BtnTip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           LblTip.Text = bookRecommendation.ToString();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call your `RandomBook()` method each time the button is clicked:

```
private void BtnTip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bookRecommendation = FileLoader.RandomBook();
    LblTip.Text = bookRecommendation.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This answer has already been posted.

Comment: @Joel This one posted first. See the timeline.

Comment: @JQSOFT The other one was 1min before. Anyway, it has been removed now.

Comment: Yeah that did it! Thanks a lot!